# Postgres UTF-8 clobs with JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, utf-8, clob

Postgres JDBC driver seems to not handle UTF-8 clobs correctly. When you retrieve the clob the characters are not correct (you get ? marks for non ascii characters).

Supposedly this is a known issue:

- http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2010-09/msg00034.php
- https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7520
- http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2011-02/msg00032.php

Luckily for my application I generally avoid clobs so the fields that were clobs I have just made into really big varchars.

How are other people dealing with this limitation?

Comment: I bet those characters didn't make it correctly into the database in the first place. I don't have any problems with UTF-8 characters and the JDBC driver. But it sure would be interesting what you think a "CLOB" in Postgres is. Especially as you converted that to varchar

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its not what I think a clob is in postgres its what hibernate thinks it should be :)

Comment: ah that dreaded Hibernate thing again.

Comment: The fields look fine in the debugger before they go into the database then when they come back out nbsp (U+00A0) turn into <?>.

Comment: the root cause is that [lob object seem to be stored in ascii with jdbc driver].
[lob object seem to be stored in ascii with jdbc driver]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993701

Answer (score 7):

Adding @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringClobType") to the clob description in hibernate solves it for me.

Comment: I was trying to keep it to only JPA and not any Hibernate specifics +1 though.

Comment: Normally I used the annotation 
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
but ran into problems deploying my application with Oracle as database. However, 
     @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringClobType")
works with Oracle and Postgres. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

clob? You mean `text` or `varchar`, PostgreSQL doesn't have clob datatype. The PostgreSQL JDBC driver doesn't have problems with that, it would be useless without UTF8 support. It works fine over here.

Comment: When I said clob I meant "text" as that is what Hibernate/JPA creates the column as for @Lob fields. Clob is what JDBC calls Postgres text fields.

Comment: are you using Hibernate if so what are you annotating your fields as?

Comment: We're using Hibernate and utf8. It's all pretty default, nothing special. The Java programmers did the original configuration, I can't help you with the annotations. Sorry