# How to fetch TEXT column value from postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a the following simple table in postgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( id bigint NOT NULL, text_column text, );
```

The values of the text_column , as I see them in the phpPgAdmin web site, are numbers (long).
As I read, postgreSQL keeps a pointer to the actual data.
How can I fetch the actual string value of the text_column?
Doing:

```
select text_column from data
```

returns numbers...

Thanks

Comment: Are you ***absolutely*** sure the text_column is defined as `text`?  The behaviour you are describing sounds as if the column is defined as `oid` - which is the stupid default behaviour of Hibernate when creating `LOB` columns. Can you copy and paste the output of the  `\d+ data` command in `psql`? Make sure you do show us the ***exact*** output, not some kind of "obfuscated" one.

Comment: Checkout this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4488693/330315 and this http://www.shredzone.de/cilla/page/299/string-lobs-on-postgresql-with-hibernate-36.html and this http://stackoverflow.com/q/5043992/330315

Answer (score 57):

Following helped us:

```
select convert_from(loread(lo_open(value::int, x'40000'::int), x'40000'::int),  'UTF8') from t_field;
```

where `value` is field, which contains `TEXT`, and t_field is obviously name of table.

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you.

Comment: It's probably obvious but the above command does a SELECT ALL essentially. You can also target individual records by using a where clause. E.g. select convert_from(loread(lo_open(value::int, x'40000'::int), x'40000'::int),  'UTF8') from t_field where id=5;

Comment: How to delete those records? I can see the text as you describe but If I truncate or drop the table my DB size is not changed. I really want to delete those records

Comment: @gunescelil Does VACUUM FULL work for you?

Comment: Actually and fortunately we are still not on the production with that code. So I deleted all the postgres table and saved my disk. But later I saw some interfaces of large objects. Maybe someone can use those interfaces to delete the records

Answer (score 4):

Provided it's text_column is text, which means it's an oid, this should work too :

```sql
select convert_from(lo_get(text_column::oid), 'UTF8') from data;
```

Answer (score 3):

From psql run \lo_export ID FILE where ID is the number stored in the text column in your table and FILE is the path and filename for the results.  The number is a reference to the large object table.  You can view its contents by running \lo_list.

Answer (score -2):

Works fine , May be the field values are in numbers:

```
 > \d+ type

 Column    | Type    

 name      |  text   

 test_id   | integer
```

> select name from type;

```
  name 

   AAA
```