# Heroku dataclip returns number instead of text column value

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have a simple Postgres table `audit` with the following columns

```
audit
date varchar
record text
```

The table was autogenerated by Spring Data on the application startup (I did not prepare DDL).

Now when I'm creating dataclip

```
select * from audit
```

it's returning me for example:

```
2021-11-24 22836979
2021-11-23 22785154
2021-11-25 22845754
2021-11-26 22858755
2021-11-27 22864701
```

however there are some text values in `record` column (my Spring Boot application is able to parse it and display on front end of my application)

Why is this happening? Is it specific to Heroku Dataclips tool?

Comment: `date varchar` Date is a keyword, you should give it a different name. And if it is a `date`, why not store it in a `DATE` type column? (BTW: `RECORD` is a keyword, too)

Comment: Maybe you are right but it's working completely fine, the application is reading values properly just Heroku Dataclips for some reason does not display text value. Thanks for your suggestions - this is super simple table and the business meaning of 'date' column is not to keep there a real date just to make sure that audit is saved once per day - it could be even int counter.

Comment: I'd trust Heroku's output, but double-check in a database client of your choosing. Are you sure Spring isn't doing some magic behind the scenes?

Comment: Ok I guess I found the issue - I declared the field (column) as a `LOB` and seems that fetching it is quite problematic in general (not only in Heroku)

Comment: This one helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155648/how-to-fetch-text-column-value-from-postgresql (however I'm not sure is this the simplest way)